# faking reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, multiple-accounts

I have the impression that some users are exploiting more accounts to fake their reputation. It happened, more than once, that I got a wrong, or very inaccurate answer to a question which has been voted up with an incredibly high pace. Has it ever happened to you? If this problem exists how is stack overflow considering to address it?

Comment: They are called sock puppets. You flag them for moderator attention.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer was wrong? (Alternatively, are you sure it was malicious as opposed to a misunderstanding on the part of the upvoters?) Do you have a link to an example?